# Wordpress Edit Image Button Disappeared

Tags: php, wordpress

Have a UGC app being run by WP 3.7.1 (I know I need to upgrade to 3.8.1).  Users upload images, admin can approve/reject, all good.  Admin also HAD the ability to edit an image (rotate being the biggest need) directly in the WP Media Edit screen.  All of sudden this button has disappeared.

I have seen this as a fairly common bug from a few years past, but common solutions don't seem to be working.
I have confirmed that PHP GD is running on the server and I have disabled a number of plugins.  These are the two common solutions I've seen listed before.  Neither have resolved this issue for me.

Any thoughts to why this button would have disappeared or ways to ensure it is enabled?

Answer (score -1):

Check is dir '/wp-content/uploads' writable.